# If $\Delta Q/ T$ approximates the entropy change of some transition, is it inclusive of the entropy from volume change?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

At the point of a transition where latent heat must be added to some substance, entropy change can be approximated by $\Delta Q/ T$. At these points, the volume of the substance also increases, which should also contribute to an increase in entropy. Does this mean that $\Delta Q/ T$ is a poor approximation for $\Delta S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no.

Let me show you some relations considering the process to be reversible;

We have from first law of thermodynamics;

$$dU= \delta Q- \delta W\;.$$

Now, since there is pressure-volume work as you speculate, we can take $\delta W= p\;dV$ so as to make the first law look as  $$nc_V\;dT= \delta Q- p\;dV$$ where $c_V$ is the molar heat capacity at constant volume.

Rearranging them a bit & using ideal-Gas law, we get $$\frac{\delta Q}{T}= nR\frac{dV}{V}+ nc_V\frac{dT}{T}\;.$$

$\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ is what we call entropy change.

Have you observed that only $\delta Q$ matters in our definition of entropy? We don't care what that heat energy does; anything can go on in the right hand side of the relation but what matters is only what amount of heat energy is consumed or released during the process in order to evaluate entropy change.

So, there is no poor approximation in calculating only the heat energy & using to find the entropy change without bothering much about what that heat energy is doing- be it increasing the volume or doing work on the surroundings. We are concerned only with the left part of the relation.